# C++: function argument of instance of any subclass of given base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm learning C++, this is a noob question...

I have a base class `Life`:

```
#include "GameObject.h"

class Life : public GameObject {
  private:

  public:
    Life(int x, int y);
    virtual void act() = 0;
    bool moveBy(int x, int y);
    bool moveTo(int x, int y);
};
```

and a subclass `Player`:

```
#include "Life.h"

class Player : public Life {
  private:

  public:
    Player(int x, int y);
    void act(); // inherited as virtual function from Life
};
```

Then there is a separate class that works with all subclasses of `Life`:

```
#include "Life.h"


struct living_beings {
  Life * being;
  struct living_beings * next;
  struct living_beings * prev;
};


class Timekeeper {
  private:
    long currentTime;
    living_beings * actors;

  public:
    Timekeeper();
    void step();
    long getTime();
    bool registerObject(Life * o);
};
```

When I call the following in the main code, I get compiler errors:

```
  Timekeeper tc;
  Player player(40,12);
  tc.registerObject(player);
```

The errors:

```
error: cannot convert ‘Player’ to ‘Life*’
   37 |   tc.registerObject(player);
      |                     ^~~~~~
      |                     |
      |                     Player
In file included from src/main.cpp:4:
src/Timekeeper.h:23:32: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘bool Timekeeper::registerObject(Life*)’
   23 |     bool registerObject(Life * o);
```

I *belive* I understand that the error occurs because the method definition expects an instance of `Life` and won't allow a subclass but I'm clueless how to resolve this.

Comment: The error is because a pointer to an object is expected. Either pass by reference `registerObject(Life& l)` or change the call to `tc.registerObject(&player);`

Comment: @Quimby: in either case, you need to be very careful that the reference does not become dangling, eg if `player` is a local in some function and that function returns.  It may make more sense to use a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending on what the OP is trying to do.